# Ionic Network type = null

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic3

Iam dev one app in Ionic v2 ts. My network.type is equal null. 
What the problem ?

```js
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  providers: [ProviderAccessApi]
})
export class HomePage {
  user : string;
  pass:string;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public providerAPI:ProviderAccessApi, private platform: Platform, public alertCtrl : AlertController, public network : Network) {
      console.log('HomePage carragada com sucesso')
      alert(network.type);
  }
```

Comment: Are you waiting for the platform to be ready before trying to access to `network.type`?

Comment: no ... How do I do that ?

Comment: I've added how to do it as an answer. If the issue is still there, we can try with other things as well...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First please notice that you should place the network-related code inside of `this.platform.ready().then(() => {...});` to execute it when the platform is ready.

```
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  providers: [ProviderAccessApi]
})
export class HomePage {
  user : string;
  pass:string;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
              public providerAPI: ProviderAccessApi, 
              private platform: Platform, 
              public alertCtrl : AlertController, 
              public network : Network) {

      console.log('HomePage carragada com sucesso');

      this.platform.ready().then(() => {
          // Now all cordova plugins are ready!
          alert(network.type);
      });

  }
}
```

Comment: How did you installed the plugin?. Also try making a console log with the network property to see what we have there: `console.log(network)`.

Comment: its great, but function in device

Comment: I've updated the answer. Since it's a cordova plugin, it will only work on a simulator / real device.

Comment: np, glad to help :)

Comment: @sebaferreras as the plugin is supporting browser platform, why won't this work in case of browser

Comment: You're right @PratikSinha, I've edited the answer. Thanks for pointing that out :)